# Indentation of XML not working as expected

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to create an XML file using string data. (Which is itself in XML format.) But the main problem is that the XML that I have created is not properly formatted. I have used XmlWriterSettings to format the XML, but it does not seem to be working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code.

```
    string unformattedXml = @"<datas><data1>sampledata1</data1><datas>";

    XmlWriterSettings xmlSettingsWithIndentation = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true};
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, xmlSettingsWithIndentation))
       {

           writer.WriteRaw(unformattedXml);
       }
```

Actually when I load this string in an XmlDocument and then saves it as a file, it was formatted. I just wanted to know why it was not working with XmlWriter.

You help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I think that `Indent = true` doesn't apply to WriteRaw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you use a `XmlReader` instead of a raw string.

(I expect it is a typo when your last XML element is not closed property, and that by formatting you refer to correct indentation):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string unformattedXml = @"<datas><data1>sampledata1</data1></datas>";

        var rdr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(unformattedXml));

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        var xmlSettingsWithIndentation =  new XmlWriterSettings 
        { 
            Indent = true
        };

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlSettingsWithIndentation))
            writer.WriteNode(rdr, true);
        
        Console.WriteLine(sb);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<datas>
  <data1>sampledata1</data1>
</datas>
```

Please cf. similar questions:
[XmlWriter.WriteRaw indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789370/xmlwriter-writeraw-indentation)
[XML indenting when injecting an XML string into an XmlWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858630/xml-indenting-when-injecting-an-xml-string-into-an-xmlwriter)

Answer (score 1):

To ignore white space, try this:

```
private static string FormatXml(string unformattedXml) 
{
    //First read the xml, ignoring whitespace.
    var readeroptions = new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true };
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(unformattedXml), readeroptions);
   
    //Then write it out with indentation.
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var xmlSettingsWithIndentation = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }; 
                  
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xmlSettingsWithIndentation))
        writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
            
    return sb.ToString();
}
```