# WCF REST Service - XML response indentation

Tags: wcf

I have WCF rest service returning XML/RSS feeds. Some methods return data contracts, some Rss20FeedFormatter, and some are streams.

In all cases XML returns without any indentation. But I have requirement to return it formatted with indentations.

Is it possible to enable XML response indentation for WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the xml output onto an xmlDocument and use XmlTextWriter to add "indent" settings.

Or you can use a simple xslt to transform the output xml onto the format that you want. for indent use

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
```

Comment: the first method is ok but how to the second method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if WCF services can return formatted responses but here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858630/xml-indenting-when-injecting-an-xml-string-into-an-xmlwriter) to a nice method for formatting XML easily that you could implement from the calling source code.