# XmlWriter with namespaces and .WriteNode()

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am writing some code which will create an Excel .xml file. The file is highly structured and formatted in a constant way, so there are some 3000 lines of the file which do not change. After seeing the answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858630/xml-indenting-when-injecting-an-xml-string-into-an-xmlwriter), I adopted this solution to create the file.

The code is as follows

```
XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.Indent = true;
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("results.xml", writerSettings);

writer.WriteStartDocument();
writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("mso-application", "progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"");
writer.WriteStartElement("Workbook", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "o", null, "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "x", null, "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "ss", null, "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "html", null, "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");
string str = "<DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">\n  <Author>Bananal</Author>\n  <LastAuthor>PedroK</LastAuthor>\n  <LastPrinted>2013-08-01T22:10:44Z</LastPrinted>\n  <Created>2013-07-17T21:18:47Z</Created>\n  <LastSaved>2013-12-16T17:44:10Z</LastSaved>\n  <Version>14.00</Version>\n </DocumentProperties>";
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings);
writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
str = "<OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">\n  <AllowPNG/>\n </OfficeDocumentSettings>";
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings);
writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
str = "<ExcelWorkbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">\n  <WindowHeight>12432</WindowHeight>\n  <WindowWidth>23256</WindowWidth>\n  <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>\n  <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>\n  <TabRatio>755</TabRatio>\n  <ActiveSheet>9</ActiveSheet>\n  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>\n  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>\n </ExcelWorkbook>";
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings);
writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
str = "<Styles>\n  <Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">\n   <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>\n   <Borders/>\n   <Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#000000\"/>\n   <Interior/>\n   <NumberFormat/>\n   <Protection/>\n  </Style></Styles>"
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings);
writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
```

In this way, I have batched everything as efficiently as I can think of. This works well until the last segment (regarding the `<Styles>`), where `writer.WriteNode()` throws an exception saying `'ss' is an undeclared namespace.` Have I done something wrong regarding the definition of the namespaces or is there something else I have to do with the raw string to make it work with `.WriteNode()`?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlWriter`? This looks like very complicated code which would be trivial using LINQ to XML. It also doesn't help that you appear to have XML embedded directly within your C# (the `Styles` element), which means it's not valid C# at all...

Comment: Oh my, yes, I've corrected the typo. That was a mistake when copying and pasting. The original version has more than just one Style, but I deleted the rest since it isn't relevant to the problem at hand and clearly forgot to place the quotation marks. This number of styles is actually part of the problem. There's hundreds of them and I don't know how Linq could help me with that. That's why I used the method presented in the link, since it allows me to simply throw them all in at once and let the writer deal with them itself.

Comment: Not LINQ in general, but LINQ to XML - it's simply a much cleaner way of creating XML, in my view. In particular, if you already have some XML that you want to include it's very easy to just parse that and add appropriate nodes. I wouldn't suggest keeping it all *in the code* though - I'd probably have a separate XML file which is loaded separately.

Comment: That had occurred to me, but I didn't see much of a point. Other than readibility (which is not something to be dismissed, I know), is there any other advantage to reading from an external file? Is there a difference in performance or total file size?

Comment: Well if you start off with a valid XML file, once it's parsed you won't get the kind of error you've got at the moment - and if it *does* fail to parse, that just shows you need to fix the XML. It separates the data errors from any coding errors. Any remaining code will also be a lot simpler, making it much easier to find any other coding errors. I wasn't thinking of performance at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an XML Reader the xml supplied needs to be valid. If you use namespace aliases on attibutes or elements it is required to also qualify the namespace.

**Quick fix solution**
You have to add the namespaces `ss` and `x` to your Styles tag like so:

```
 str = "<Styles xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">\n  <Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">\n   <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>\n   <Borders/>\n   <Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#000000\"/>\n   <Interior/>\n   <NumberFormat/>\n   <Protection/>\n  </Style></Styles>";
 reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings);
 writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
```

**Alternative solution**
Provide a [parserContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc8bact5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the namespaces needed to the reader. The pros is that you don't have to change the xmlmarkup you currently have.

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");

//Create the XmlParserContext (this can be reused in every reader!)
XmlParserContext ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.None);

/* other code here */

str = "<Styles >\n  <Style ss:ID=\"Default\" ss:Name=\"Normal\">\n   <Alignment ss:Vertical=\"Bottom\"/>\n   <Borders/>\n   <Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#000000\"/>\n   <Interior/>\n   <NumberFormat/>\n   <Protection/>\n  </Style></Styles>";
reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(str), readerSettings, ctx); // NOTICE ctx here
writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
```

**Side note**
It looks like you are producing a file for use by Excel. Did you consider [The Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.workbook.aspx)?

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of the Open XML SDK (I am woefully ignorant of things, I am very much a hobby programmer). I'm taking a look at it now, seems interesting.

Comment: It is basically a managed wrapper around the xmlstore with some benefits if you have relations between nodes. I don't think your code will be much smaller in the end...